# How to Display all posts on a page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show all the posts of my wordpress blog on a single blog page, for some reason the solutions that I am finding in Google are 5-6 years old, I was wondering which is the best and easiest way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be the best one in my case ;)

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'orderby' => 'DESC'
        );
    $home_query = new WP_Query($args);  
    if($home_query->have_posts()):  while($home_query->have_posts()) : $home_query->the_post();
        get_template_part('pages'); 
        endwhile;
    else:
        get_template_part( 'no-results', 'home' );
    endif;
```

and in pages.php

```
<section class="page-<?php echo get_post_type();?>-<?php the_ID();?> id="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">
        <div class="container">

            <?php

            the_content();

            ?>

        </div> 
    </section>
```

Comment: Where should i put the first code ? in functions.php ? I actually just want a page /blog/all which shows all posts

Comment: the first part goes in index. Php og the theme, and the rest in a file named pages.php in root if the theme as well, but if you found a plugin that does the job, that will do the job, just make sure it doesn't make your app slower ;-)